# Working with subsettable functions and optim()

Tags: r

I have one question regarding the code example:

```
testfunc<-function(x) {
   f<-x^2
   help.var<- somefunction(f)
   g.grad<- 2* helpvar
   return(c(f,g.grad))
}
```

When I try to optimize this function, optim for example wants me to provide two separate functions, one function evaluation and one gradient evaluation. So,

```
optim(20,testfunc[1],testfunc[2])
```

gives: object of type closure is not subsettable.

I solved this by defining two functions, and defining g.grad as global variable:

```
testfunc1<-function(x) {
          f<-x^2
          help.var<<- somefunction(f)

           return(f)
}
help.function<-function(x){
           return(2*help.var)
}
optim(20,testfunc1,help.function)
```

Since the original problem is much more involved, the code gets easily confusing. Do you have any idea to solve this problem more elegant (maybe without using global variables at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is just how to store two functions in an object, then one possible solution is

```
testfunc <- list(
   f = function(x) x^2,
   g.grad = function(x) 2*x
)
```

then you can do

```
optim(20,testfunc[[1]],testfunc[[2]])
```

Comment: That is definitely the kind of solution, I´m looking for. After your suggestion I noticed that my example is lacking in an important feature: the gradient depends on the function evaluation. X^2 may be not the best example here.

Comment: So why can't you just use ` g.grad = function(x) 2* somefunction(x)` with this solution? I don't see the problem. It doesn't help that your reproducible example is no longer reproducible because `somefunction` isn't defined.